# iframe overlays content

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I got this code:

```
    <div id="resizeDiv"><div id="title">Lol</div><div id="content"><iframe src='todo.php' height='100%' width='100%' frameborder='0px'></iframe></div></div>
```

and this is the css:

```
    #title{
      height: 25px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #c0c0c0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    }
    #content{
      margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
```

and i use jquery to allow resizing of the box.
but the iframe goes out the box exacly 25px.
i tried:

```
    margin-bottom: 25px;
```

but that doesnt work does anyone has an idea what i am doeing wrong?

Comment: is `title` exactly 25px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `overflow: hidden`:

```
#resizeDiv {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

Comment: IT WORKS WHEN I PUTTED IT IN THE resizeDiv CLASS THANK YOU!!

Comment: @lexvdpoel i was updating ma answer, you did it faster than me :)

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow: hidden` does not actually correct the problem, it just hides it, the problem is the height of the title is not taken into account, in the resizer function in jQuery I would account for the title height using somthing like:

```
$("#content > iframe").height($("#resizeDiv").innerHeight() - $("#title").outerHeight());
```